# Get Values Based on First Dropdown Selection

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

**jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#FirstDD").change(function(){
        $('#SecDD').load('inc/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML/PHP**

```
<select style="width:300px;" id="FirstDD" name="userListingCategory">
                <!--onchange="$('#SecDD').load('inc/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);"-->
                      <option  disabled="disabled">Category...</option>
                      <?php while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                      {$categoryID = $row['catID']; echo "<option value=". $categoryID . ">" .$row['catName']."</option>";}
                    unset($sth2);
                    ?>

                </select> 
               <?php require_once('inc/subcategories.php'); ?>
```

**Subcategories.php**

```
<?php require_once('db/dbc.php');
#GET SELECT sub-category names
$pdo3 = new PDO($h1, $u, $p);
$pdo3->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth3 = $pdo3->prepare("
SELECT scatID, scatName 
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE C.catID = SC.catID
;");
$sth3->execute(array());
?>

<select style="width:340px;" id="SecDD" name="userListingSCategory" style="display:none">
<option  disabled="disabled">Sub-Category...</option> 
<?php
#Get subcats     
while($row = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{echo "<option value=". $row['scatID'] . ">" .$row['scatName']."</option>";}
unset($sth3);
?>
</div>
</select>
```

Subcategories outputs all the subcategories for that table with the necessary fields selected.

When I click a `CATEGORY`, the `SUBCATEGORY` dropdown `disabled value` is erased but NO DATA is filled in.

Output of subcategories.php:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc1J2.png

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using onchange= you can try to use a jquery event listener:

```
$("#FirstDD").change(function(){
    $('#SecDD').load('inc/subcategories.php?scatID='+this.value);
});
```

Comment: how to I run that in my onchange()

Comment: you don't put it in onchange(); you put it in a seperate <script> </script> block

Comment: I quickly figured that out, please see the updated. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`Subcategories.php` never outputs anything. You need to loop the returned data and output some HTML `<option>`s in order for your existing JS to work - the AJAX call will work, but the PHP script never outputs anything, so the display will not be updated as there is nothing to update it with...

Comment: So I see from you edit... But what I also now see is that your are loading a `<select>` into a `<select>` - `jQuery.load()` places the returned data *inside* the element you call it on. You either need to remove the `<select>` from `Subcategories.php`, and just output the `<option>`s, or (preferably) put the `<select>` inside a block-level element (like a `<div>`) in the main page, and call `$.load()` on that element instead. Also, you need to make sure that `Subcategories.php` works at all - load it in a browser and make sure the output is what you expect...

Comment: Subcategories.php - outputs exactly what's needed. Could you show what your talking about with Select and jquery.load() ?

Comment: DaveRandom - neither of these seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Say you call `$('#someDiv').load` - the innerHTML of the element `someDiv` is replaced with the result of the AJAX call. If you do it with a `<select>`, but the page called also outputs a `<select>`, what your end up with is `<select><select><!--options--></select><select>` - so the page requested by the AJAX call should output *only* the `<option>`s, not the `<select>`.

Comment: DaveRandom -- please see updated code here: http://pastebin.com/dgK1iqNq (SO wont let me revise my cost)

Comment: DavidRandom - it looks like its successfully loading using the ajax. My SQL seems to be messed up. I'm ending the $sth2, and trying to use $categoryID after that. But I have to use $sth3

Comment: What output do you get if you load `subcategories.php` in a browser?